# pygame Отталкивание мячов

Tags: python, pygame

Пытаюсь заставить шары отталкиваться друг от друга, получилось вроде отследить
момент столкновения (правильно ли я это сделал?), оттолкнуть их не получается, метод reflect почему-то не срабатывает. Что я делаю не так?

```
import pygame
import random

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, startpos, velocity, startdir):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(startpos)
        self.velocity = velocity
        print("startdir", startdir)
        print("not norm", pygame.math.Vector2(startdir))
        self.dir = pygame.math.Vector2(startdir).normalize()
        print("norm", self.dir)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("small_ball.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))

    def reflect(self, NV):
        self.dir = self.dir.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.dir * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)

        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.reflect((1, 0))
        if self.rect.right >= 700:
            self.reflect((-1, 0))
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.reflect((0, 1))
        if self.rect.bottom >= 700:
            self.reflect((0, -1))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('noname')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
start, velocity, direction = (200, 200), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_1 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)
start, velocity, direction = (200, 200), 10, (random.random(), random.random())
ball_2 = Ball(start, velocity, direction)
all_balls.add(ball_1)
all_balls.add(ball_2)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    blocks_hit = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(all_balls, all_balls, False, False)
    if blocks_hit:
        for _, sprites_hit in blocks_hit.items():
            if len(sprites_hit) > 1:
                sprite_1 = sprites_hit[0]
                sprite_2 = sprites_hit[1]
                print("Столконвение")
                sprite_2.reflect((0, 1)) # Ничего не происходит

    all_balls.update()

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 700, 700), 1)
    all_balls.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: small_ball.png]

Comment: Т.к. ТС не предоставил картинки мяча - [картинка для тестов](https://i.imgur.com/zkiNpJZ.png) (назвать *small_ball.png*)

Comment: @Стас, прикрепил изображение.